# OpenUI5 XML View attribute as variable

Tags: xml, sapui5

I'm using OpenUI5 and have an overall framework XMLView and Controller and want to display another XMLView dynamically based on certain conditions. e.g.

```
<mvc:View controllerName="openui5.view.Framework" xmlns="sap.m"
xmlns:core="sap.ui.core" xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc" >

<Page id="frameworkPage" title="{i18n>DetailTitle}" showNavButton="true"
    navButtonPress="onBack">
    <Button id="saveButton" text="Save" type="Accept" icon="sap-icon://save"
        press="onSave" />
    <Button id="nextButton" text="Next" type="Accept" icon="sap-icon://action"
        press="onNext" />
    <content>   
        <mvc:XMLView id="subView" viewName="{myViewVariable}"></mvc:XMLView>
    </content>
</Page>
```

Is it possible to specify a value to myViewVariable dynamically at runtime?

Cheers,XML

Answer (score 0):

I'm quite sure there's no possibility for something like conditionals or data binding for the specification of your content in the XML View.
There are two possibilities I know of:

- You could leave your content tag empty and add content during runtime using the addContent(oContent) method in your controller dynamically e.g. inside an event handler for a button.
- You could switch to JSView instead of XML. There you could use things like conditionals and loops but consider: in comparison to the first solution it will only do this once at the initialization of your view

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to do something similar with the release of 1.28. This update is going to introduce [XML Templating](https://ui5.sap.com/#/topic/5ee619fc1370463ea674ee04b65ed83b).